# css border size over my title and after a image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble trying to implement the styling shown in this image using CSS. My problem is how to make the horizontal yellow line over the title "nossos numeros" and the vertical blue lines between "Cursos", "Alunos" and "Aulas".

I'm using also Bootstrap 4.

I want this:

[image]

I did this:

[image]

```
   <section class="bg-light" id="portfolio" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <p class="font-square2" style="border-top: 5px yellow solid;">
        NOSSOS <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;NÚMEROS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"  style="padding-top: 50px; border-right: 1px blue solid; ">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/icone_cursos.png">
        <div class="portfolio-caption">
          <p class="font-square"> 1123 </p>
          <p class="font-square"><strong>Cursos</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-top: 50px; border-right: 1px blue solid;">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/icone_alunos.png">
        <div class="portfolio-caption">
          <p class="font-square"> 34534 </p>
          <p class="font-square"><strong>Alunos</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-top: 65px;">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/icone_aulas.png">
        <div class="portfolio-caption">
          <p class="font-square"> 4566 </p>
          <p class="font-square"><strong>Aulas</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

but now how I can set the size of the border that I want with a color ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add your HTML? You can only set the border width, not the length. You will have to create a separate element or something

Comment: ok, i edit and add this

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can't. You have to use preudoelements. Example:

```
div {
  width   : 200px;
  height  : 50px;  
}

div:before {
  content : "";
  position: absolute;
  left    : 0;
  bottom  : 0;
  height  : 1px;
  width   : 50%; 
  border-bottom:1px solid yellow;
}
<div>Item 1</div>
<div>Item 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo elements for this

Try this

```
#fortopborder:before {
    height: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    content: '';
}

#forrightborder:after {
    display: block; 
    content: '';
    background: blue;
    Width: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -120px;
    Float:right;
}
```